# The App Store Icon (Layered) not shown in my iTunes Connect page

Tags: xcode, app-store, tvos

I uploaded my tvOS app into iTunes Connect. But the App Store icon is not shown. I have Large App Icon(1280x768), Small App Icon(400x240), Top Shelf Image(1920x720) in my assets:

[image]

But in iTunes Connect:

[image]

The **App Store Icon(Layered)** is empty. What could be the reason? Thanks

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's not about programming.

Comment: It's still a question from developer although it's not a question directly related to programming.

Comment: Do your PNG images used to create the icon contain alpha channels?

Comment: It was shown after 1 day. Maybe it took some time to process?

Answer (score 0):

After you upload the app, you need to save and exit iTunes Connect and then sign in again. The image will then be shown. The image used is the app store icon (layered).